# Spring-security remember me functionality not working

Tags: grails, spring-security

I write the below given code in config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
    'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName='grails_remember_me'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds=31*24*60*60
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.parameter='_spring_security_remember_me'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.key='monitoringApp' 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.useSecureCookie=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent=false
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
```

i write the below given code on my gsp page

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me' id='remember_me'
<g:if test='${hasCookie}'>checked='checked'</g:if>/>
<g:message code="springSecurity.login.remember.me.label"/>
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

My controller all action are fully authenticated using spring security     `@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])` But i cannot able to use benefit of spring security remember me functionality.Please help me .

I am using grails version 2.3.0 and spring security :"spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"

Comment: Is the issue that your users are being prompted to login even after using the remember me feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why your users, which have used the remember me feature of Spring security are still being prompted to login is because is `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` not the same as `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`.

**IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED**
requires the user to be authenticated *through a remember-me cookie or an explicit login*.

**IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY**
requires the user to be fully authenticated with an explicit login.

All of this is outlined in the very well written [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html).

Since you want to allow users to access things either by being remembered or logging in you should strongly consider using `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` instead of `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` since it supports both cases.

Comment: Please refer to this doc for [Spring Security Core Plugin - Reference Documentation version 3.0.0.M2](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html)

Comment: I've been starring at this for hours changing every possible value for remember-me and various repository settings. It all comes back to some silly decision I made weeks ago.